# Strip not working properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, strip

I have a string

```
s = "        \r\n Displays the unique ID number assigned to the\r\nAlias Person."
```

I want to remove this starting space but its not removing even these quotations marks also.

I tried

```
s = s.strip!
s = s.gsub!('"','')
```

Comment: What does `s.chars.map(&:ord)` return?

Comment: Works fine for me:
`s.strip! => "Displays the unique ID number assigned to the\r\nAlias Person."`
ruby 2.4.0

Comment: @SebastianPalma [160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 32, 67, 108, 105, 99, 107, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 98, 117, 116, 116, 111, 110, 32, 116, 111, 32, 111, 112, 101, 110, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 83, 101, 97, 114, 99, 104, 32, 67, 114, 105, 116, 101, 114, 105, 97, 32, 112, 111, 112, 45, 117, 112, 32, 119, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 32, 116, 111, 32, 115, 101, 97, 114, 99, 104, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 80, 101, 114, 115, 111, 110, 32, 73, 68, 46]

Comment: That shouldn't be a 160 for being able to strip, they're non-braking whitespaces, replace them with "normal" spaces (32), and it'll work.

Comment: how??......................

Comment: can you please post output which you get along with question @HaseebAhmad

Comment: You might try `s = s.gsub(/\A[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+\z/, "")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have in your string are non-breaking whitespaces, the difference is somethings non-visible if you don't use any help in your editor:

```
p "        \r\n Displays the unique ID number assigned to the\r\nAlias Person."
p "        \r\n Displays the unique ID number assigned to the\r\nAlias Person."
```

But if you map each character within the string you can see the difference:

```
[32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 13, 10, 32, ...]
[160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 13, 10, 32, ...]
```

Those 160 are the ones you can't replace, you must remove them manually, or by rejecting the ones matching 160 and then joining and converting again:

```
string = "        \r\n Displays the unique ID number assigned to the\r\nAlias Person."
p string.chars.reject { |char| char.ord == 160 }.join
# "\r\n Displays the unique ID number assigned to the\r\nAlias Person."
```

Comment: didnt know that these even existed :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code. if you are trying to remove quotation marks from beginning and end of the string, it will not be removed. This is how ruby represents a string. Try to define a string with single quote like this:-

```
2.4.2 :005 > str = 'aaa'
 => "aaa"
```

Comment: and how to remove space?

Comment: which space character?

Comment: space from start

Comment: which ruby version you are using? run `ruby -v`.